# TryParseExact not working properly for TimeSpan and custom format not working for "\" in DateTime and DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, blazor

Issue 1 :
When attempting to parse **TimeSpan** values using the TryParseExact method not working properly. also TryParseExact method with a format string containing "" as the escape character, the parsing operation fails to produce the expected results. Instead, it throws an exception or returns an incorrect result. I have attached the sample link below

```
    string timeValue = "01:45";

    TimeSpan dateTimeVal;

    if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeValue, "hh:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out dateTimeVal))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time successfully parsed: " + dateTimeVal.ToString("hh:mm"));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse time: " + timeValue);
    }
```

Issue 2 :
When attempting to parse **DateTime** and **DateTimeOffset** values using the TryParseExact method with a format string containing "" as the escape character, the parsing operation fails to produce the expected results. Instead, it throws an exception or returns an incorrect result.

But however while using "//"symbol or other charactors like @,# are working fine.

working sample:

```
    string dateTimeValue1 = @"09$$:30";
    DateTime parsedDateTime1;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeValue1, @"HH$$:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DateTime successfully parsed: ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse DateTime: " + dateTimeValue);
    }
```

Not working sample :

```
    string dateTimeValue = @"09\\:30";
    DateTime parsedDateTime;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeValue, @"HH\\:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DateTime successfully parsed: " + parsedDateTime.ToString(@"HH\\:mm"));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse DateTime: " + dateTimeValue);
    }
```

same like DateTimeOffset

sample Link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ry1lZe

#### Expected Behavior

TimeSpan or DateTime or DatetimeOffset value "09\:30" should be successfully parsed and printed as "09:30".

#### Steps To Reproduce

issue 1 :

Run the attached sample,
see the issue with TryParseExact method on Output tab

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("09\\:00", "HH\\\\:mm", null)

Comment: Look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings. Read the highlighted _Important_ note.

Comment: Works fine when you do the correct escaping and the correct `ToString` formats https://dotnetfiddle.net/PL51hr